# Sequelize v6 GROUP Columns with Same Name

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using the group parameter in a count query (db.rv.count()) and two of the columns have the same name. This produces a Sequelize error that says duplicate field name `name`.  Is there any way around this?

My group parameters looks like this.

```
group: ['rule.id', 'rulev.name', 'state.name']
```

Here's the count query Sequelize logs:

```
SELECT `rule`.`id`,
       `rulev`.`name`,
       `states`.`name`,
       COIUNT(`rulev`.`id`) AS `count`
FROM `rulev`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `rule` ON `rulev`.`ruleId` = `rule`.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `states` ON `rulev`.`stateId` = `states`.`id`
WHERE `rulev`.`isnew` = FALSE
GOUP BY `rule`.`id`, `rulev`.`name`, `states`.`name`
```

The exact error is:

```
Error in results, duplicate field name `name`. (see option `checkDuplicate`)
```

Comment: Can you try to indicate those columns using `Sequelize.col`?

Comment: Never used that before so I'll have to look it up.

Comment: Tried this. Am I doing it right?  
group: [Sequelize.col('rule.id'), Sequelize.col('rulev.name'), Sequelize.col('state.name')]

Comment: And whta was the exact error?

Comment: Error in results, duplicate field name `name`.\n(set option `checkDuplicate`)

Comment: I have no idea how to use the checkDuplicate option and I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs.

Comment: THere is no such option `checkDuplicate`

Comment: `group` option accept only strings, Sequelize.col and Sequelize.fn

Comment: I am thinking the error is rather about (returned) `attributes` than `group`. Your `group` has proper namespaces. Perhaps either generated SQL or your entire `count` function code could help us understand your issue better.  Also, could you add your db as a tag?

Comment: @Emma I've added the query to the original post.  Ty!

Comment: the error "duplicate field name" is coming from `SELECT \`rulev\`.\`name\`, \`states\`.\`name\`` instead of `group by`. In SQL, if you have same column name in different table, you need to alias it to avoid this issue like `SELECT \`rulev\`.\`name\`, \`states\`.\`name\` AS \`states.name\``.  Sequelize should alias it by default for `attributes` inside of `include`.  How are you setting the `attributes` for all of them?  and is this MariaDB?

Comment: You are correct. I was able to get around this by including the fields in the attributes of the corresponding models.